# Is it possible to run entity framework 4.1 in .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I created a web application specific for the .Net version 4.0 utilizing entity framework 4.1 features. The server it is being deployed on supports up to .Net 3.5 applications. I want to port over the project to .net 3.5 but certain features seem unavailable, such as access to the  ObjectSet Class. So is it possible to port over this project with the same features, or will I have to recreate a whole new web project?

Comment: Why do you think the first number in version is 4?

Comment: I was hoping you guys would suggest a work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the download page:

> ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 requires .NET Framework 4.0 RTM to be installed.
>   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b41c728e-9b4f-4331-a1a8-537d16c6acdf&displaylang=en

It builds on EF 4, which shipped with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [download section](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2dc5ddac-5a96-48b2-878d-b9f49d87569a):

> ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 RC
>   requires .NET Framework 4.0 RTM to be
>   installed.